# C# static interface or abstract implementation

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have a program that needs to be able to interface with multiple platforms ie read/write files, read/write database or read/write web requests. The platform interface is selected from configuration and does not change while the application is running. I have a single read/write interface class which is inherited by the platform specific classes so that this is abstracted from the rest of the program.

My problem is that I have 10 classes in my framework that will need to use this interface. Instead of making multiple instances of this class, or passing a single reference to every class, I figured it would make sense to make the interface static. Unfortunately I have just learned that Interfaces cannot have static methods, static methods cannot call non-static methods and static methods cannot be abstract.

Can anyone show me another method of approaching this situation?

Edit:
Thanks for everyone's input, here is my solution based on the example given by Patrick Hofman (thank you!)

```
interface TheInterface
{
    void read();
    void write();
}


public class X : TheInterface
{
    public void read() { //do something }
    public void write() { //do something }
}

public class Y : TheInterface
{
    public void read() { //do something }
    public void write() { //do something }
}


public class FileAccessor
{
    public static TheInterface accessor;

    public static TheInterface Accessor
    {
        get
        {
            if(accessor) return accessor;
        }
    }
}
```

This can be called by any class as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    switch (Config.interface)
    {
        case "X":
            FileAccessor.accessor = new Lazy<X>();
        case "Y":
            FileAccessor.accessor = new Lazy<Y>();
        default:
            throw new Lazy<Exception>("Unknown interface: " + Config.interface);
    }

    FileAccessor.Accessor.read();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code about your scenario?! I think you could achieve your goal by using abstract class with kind of design pattern

Comment: 1) Consider using dependency injection over a singleton with static accessor. 2) if you insist on this kind of singleton, use `Lazy<T>` to implement it. 3) Why is `GetLibrary()` public?

Comment: Thanks CodesInChaos, you are right that should have been private. I am reading up on Dependency Injection now. Were you able to give an example of how it applies to my code?

Comment: There are errors in your code. Particularly, the methods in `class X` are not allowed to specify `override`. There is presumably a rename of the `library` field which is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, interfaces, or abstract classes can't be `static` themselves, but the further implementation can. Also, you can use the singleton pattern to make your life easier, and allow inheritance, etc.

```
public class X : ISomeInterface
{
    private X() { }

    public static X instance;
    public static X Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance ?? (instance = new X());
        }
    }
}
```

Or, using [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
public class X : ISomeInterface
{
    private X() { }

    public static Lazy<X> instanceLazy = new Lazy<X>(() => new X());
    public static X Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather use `Lazy<T>` for its simplicity and thread-safety.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I used a modified version of this idea in my solution which I added to the question. I would be interested to know if the way I implemented your solution was correct or if there was a better way you can see?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Agreed. The code was just as a general idea. Will update.

Comment: @Scotty: You should look into Dependency Injection. [Read further here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323705%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions, both are new concepts to me so I have done some reading. 1) Dependency Injection, I have moved the creation of the concrete class outside so that the classes are loosely coupled. 2) Lazy<T> - I can't believe c# was creating all the objects in my switch even when the lines weren't touched! I have added this there, but not to `FileAccessor.accessor` as I am 100% certain that my program will use it at some point. Have I implemented these correctly? (updated example in question)

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I am the author of the library described below.*

I don't know if this helps you, but I have written [a library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TinyReflectiveToolkit/) (very early version yet) that allows you to define static interfaces, by defining normal interfaces and decorating their methods with an attribute named [`[Static]`](https://github.com/TChatzigiannakis/TinyReflectiveToolkit/blob/master/TinyReflectiveToolkit/Contracts/StaticAttribute.cs), for example:

```
public interface IYourInterface
{
    [Static] 
    void DoTheThing();
}
```

(Note that you don't explicitly add this interface to your implementations.)

Once you have defined the interface, you can instantiate it from within your code with any valid implementation you choose:

```
return typeof(YourImplementation).ToStaticContract<IYourInterface>();
```

If the methods can't be found in `YourImplementation`, this call fails at runtime with an exception.

If the methods are found and this call is successful, then the client code can polymorphically call your static methods like this:

```
IYourInterface proxy = GetAnImplementation();
proxy.DoTheThing();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. As I this will be the only time I need to do this during this project I won't be using an additional library, however I am sure others will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Static Class which has Variable of your Interface.

```
  public static class StaticClass
  {
    public static ISomeInterface Interface;
  }
```

Now you can access the Instance from everywhere in your Framwork

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  StaticClass.Interface = new SomeClass();
}
```